# ClassCastException on reload

Tags: java, playframework

when I edit my code and reloade the play tab on localhost:3001/@tests I always get 
ClassCastExceptions when I attempt to run a test.

E.g. (just an example, but you can substitute TestClass for any class)

```
A java.lang.ClassCastException has been caught, Cannot cast TestClass to TestClass
```

This is seriously slowing down the development. Are there any solutions to that?

play version "1.2.3"

java version "1.6.0_23"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11pre) (6b23~pre11-0ubuntu1.11.10.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: could you paste the complete stacktrace? Play tests are run in a different classloader.

Answer (score 5):

This seemingly bogus exception can be caused by the two objects coming from two differect packages ( com.pack0000.TestClass & com.pack1111.TestClass ) or in a single package but loaded by two different classloaders or the class existing in two different jars.  On the line before the exception, print out xxx.getClass().getCanonicalName() and xxx.getClass().getClassLoader() for both and see if that sheds any light.